# Can all Twilio resource SIDS be considered globally unique?

Tags: database, twilio

I work on an application that stores data from multiple Twilio accounts in a single backend DB. Part of the stored data is SIDs for various resources within an account - tasks, channels, services etc.

When designing my schema, can I consider all these various types of SIDs to be unique across all accounts, or would I need to consider them only to be unique within the scope of their owning account, and specify my constraints, relationships & queries accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are globally unique :)

> A String Identifier (SID) is a unique key that is used to identify specific resources.

[source](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-a-sid)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I saw the linked doc but still thought it left room for ambiguity since it only said 'unique', rather than explicitly saying they were globally unique so wanted to be sure